# EF5 one-to-many relationship results in incorrect foreign key column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

I'm trying to configure a one-to-many relationship with navigation only on the "many" side, but can't seem to get EF to generate the right column name.

Here's the relevant schema:

```
QuoteItem
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY

QuoteItemFiles
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY
  QuoteItemId INT NOT NULL
  FileId INT NOT NULL

Files
  FileID INT PRIMARY KEY (legacy naming convention)
```

And the model:

```
public class QuoteItem
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<QuoteItemFile> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteItemFile
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public File File { get; set; }
  public QuoteItem QuoteItem { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
  public int FileID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm configuring the relationship like this:

```
public class QuoteItemMap()
{
  HasMany(x => x.Attachments)
    .WithRequired(x => x.QuoteItem)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("QuoteItemId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}

public QuoteItemFileMap()
{
  HasRequired(x => x.QuoteItem)
    .WithMany(x => x.Attachments)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("QuoteItemId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
  HasRequired(x => x.File)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("FileId")) <-- This isn't working
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

When I try to access QuoteItem.Attachments, I get "**Invalid column name 'File_FileID'.**"

Why isn't it obeying my `MapKey("FileId")` instruction?

Comment: Is it FileID or FileId?  You use both in your code example which may be part of the problem.

Comment: Is `QuoteItemFileMap` added to the modelBuilder configurations? If no, EF will use the default convention FK with underscore.

Comment: @CraigW, I've tried both without success.  I know SQL isn't case-sensitive, so it would make sense that EF wouldn't be either, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Slauma, that was it.  I had generated the mappings for existing schema using a VS extension a couple weeks ago, and then I forgot to manually add this new one yesterday.  Thanks!